# Python ClassCastException java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: python, jython

I'm receiving the below error for my event handler method when an Event is raised.

```
ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.python.core.PyMethod cannot be cast to org.sikuli.script.SikuliEventObserver
```

Can someone please tell me how I can explicitly cast my pymethod to a eventobserver

```
def PostTransactionEvent(self):
    """ wait while posting transaction handler, make it run in the foreground """
    self.screen.onAppear("PostingTrans.png", self.WaitWhilePostingTransaction)
    self.screen.observe(Timeouts.Observe, background = False)
```

event handler

```
def WaitWhilePostingTransaction(self, event):      
    self.screen.waitVanish(event.match, Timeouts.Wait)
    event.region.stopObserver()
```

Comment: source code is useful when you are posting an error message.

Comment: updated the question with source code